# What does a list next to a list mean?

Tags: python-3.x

I am confused about what does lists[outer_index][inner_index] do? I thought that when two lists are next to each other, it means the first list is the selected list and the second list indicates the index of the first list. However, that doesn't seem to be the case here.

```
def flatten(lists):
    results = []
    for outer_index in range(len(lists)): # outer index = 0, 1
        for inner_index in range(len(lists[outer_index])): # inner_index = [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
            results.append(lists[outer_index][inner_index])
    return results
n = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
print(flatten(n))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an list of lists (basically a table).

```
n = [[1, 2, 3],
     [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
```

If I do `n[0][1]` I am saying go to `row 0` and grab the element in `column 1`.

Its better to think of it this way.

```
n = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
s = n[0] # Now s = [1,2,3], the first element in n
s[1] = 2 # Because I just grabbed the second element in [1,2,3]

# This is the same as

n[0][1]
```

Comment: This is not an array of arrays but a list of lists.

Comment: @DYZ Oops thats the `C++` coming out of me.